# Looking for examples of SSO implementations without redirects and pop-ups

Tags: iframe, single-sign-on

I've spent a whole afternoon looking for real world examples of SSO logins which work **without redirects or pop-ups** - and had no luck.

Does this mean they do not exist or do I just suck at searching?

I want to be able to login from blabla.com to blablablablabla.com as well - without redirects or popups. I am looking for real examples not instructions how to pull it off.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Why do you not want users to authenticate via a pop-up?

Answer (score 1):

> real world examples of SSO logins which work without redirects or pop-ups - and had no luck.

Trust distribution is really hard.  So it's no surprise that some solutions prefer a robust solution which introduces little-to-no new requirements on the client over warts like lack of redirects.

How much control do you have over your clients?

### Authentication Options

- TLS Client-side certificate: relies on certificates associated with the client's identity to be configured for each user agent.
- Kerberos authentication: relies on an existing Kerberos system for authentication.  MS Domain Controllers may serve as an adequate Kerberos authentication infrastructure.

Each of these offers pros and cons over the other, but the main theme here is that if you raise the bar on your expectation of your clients system configuration, you can get attractive results.

If you are designing an application for a small or medium sized business, this new burden might not be too great.  Small businesses have few clients to configure and medium sized businesses may have a mature computer-imaging/deployment solution that's appropriate for including configuration items like these.

Large businesses include a great deal of bureaucracy and real world exceptions that would break these authentication choices.

Public-facing websites are a poor fit for these choices because the general public isn't experienced enough to maintain a computer configuration that's this complex.